# Unable to load my static files in Django production environment

Tags: python, django, deployment, static, railway

I am deploying my Django application to Railway.

I am following this guide, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#how-to-deploy-static-files. The app was deployed successfully but **cannot load the static files**. I followed some online tutorials on this and it is still not working. What did I miss?

**My Railway deploy log:**

```
Not Found: /static/styles/style.css
Not Found: /static/images/logo.svg
Not Found: /static/styles/style.css
Not Found: /static/images/logo.svg
Not Found: /static/images/avatar.svg
Not Found: /static/images/avatar.svg
Not Found: /static/js/script.js
Not Found: /static/js/script.js
```

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
```

Comment: how did you configure the nginx/apache/webserver?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to serve the static files through Nginx instead of django.

Do the following steps

1. Collect static files

   ```
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Update nginx config to serve the static files

   ```
   location /static/ {
       root /path/to/staticfiles;
   }
   ```

It will work like below
`Browser [request]--> Nginx [static files]`